# String Array increment each string in TextToSpeech

Tags: android

Using the text to speech API I want to change the string array to increment from index 0 string and when it reaches the end it will go back to the beginning.

At the moment it uses a random generator and the method works as follows:

```
 public static void sayHello() {
    // Select a random hello.

    int helloLength = HELLOS.length;
    String hello = HELLOS[RANDOM.nextInt(helloLength)];
    mTts.speak(hello,
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
        null);
}
```

HELLOS is the array and it holds the strings:

```
 String [] HELLOS = {"One" "Two" "Three" "Four"};
```

Appreciate any help
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to increment an index but loop around to zero again modulo is your friend.

```
int currentHelloIndex = 0;
public static void sayHello() {
    // Select a random hello.

    int helloLength = HELLOS.length;
    String hello = HELLOS[currentHelloIndex];
    currentHelloIndex = (currentHelloIndex + 1) % helloLength;
    mTts.speak(hello,
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
        null);
}
```

Comment: @Raj: And if this is to be remembered between sessions, you'll have to save the value of currentHelloIndex, e.g. using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this, very grateful. :)